# Changing column values of files in a library without triggering workflow?

Tags: workflow, column-data

I want to change the column data of some files in Shared Documents without triggering a workflow.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the workflow association temporarily from the list. Following option is available in the List Settings.

Select No New Instances to prevent new instances of this workflow from running but still allow for running instances to finish

More information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262779.aspx

Once you are done, you can restore the association.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could also set the Workflow to initiate only when new items are added to the library.  Make sure you don't run on when items are modified.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could set the Workflow to Manual temporarily and then update your documents.  Should be a quick fix with SPD.